# ParseError: 172:3 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_version"

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in

----> 1 config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py in get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override)

```
 96   with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:

 97     proto_str = f.read()
```

---> 98     text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

```
 99   if config_override:

100     text_format.Merge(config_override, pipeline_config)
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in Merge(text, message, allow_unknown_extension, allow_field_number, descriptor_pool, allow_unknown_field)

```
735       allow_field_number,

736       descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool,
```

--> 737       allow_unknown_field=allow_unknown_field)

```
738 

739
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in MergeLines(lines, message, allow_unknown_extension, allow_field_number, descriptor_pool, allow_unknown_field)

```
803                    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool,

804                    allow_unknown_field=allow_unknown_field)
```

--> 805   return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)

```
806 

807
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in MergeLines(self, lines, message)

```
828     """Merges a text representation of a protocol message into a message."""

829     self._allow_multiple_scalars = True
```

--> 830     self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)

```
831     return message

832
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in _ParseOrMerge(self, lines, message)

```
850     tokenizer = Tokenizer(str_lines)

851     while not tokenizer.AtEnd():
```

--> 852       self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)

```
853 

854   def _MergeField(self, tokenizer, message):
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in _MergeField(self, tokenizer, message)

```
980 

981       else:
```

--> 982         merger(tokenizer, message, field)

```
983 

984     else:  # Proto field is unknown.
```

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in _MergeMessageField(self, tokenizer, message, field)

1055       if tokenizer.AtEnd():

1056         raise tokenizer.ParseErrorPreviousToken('Expected "%s".' % (end_token,))

-> 1057       self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)

1058

1059     if is_map_entry:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py in _MergeField(self, tokenizer, message)

```
947         raise tokenizer.ParseErrorPreviousToken(

948             'Message type "%s" has no field named "%s".' %
```

--> 949             (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
950
951     if field:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `fine_tune_checkpoint_version` line (line 172 according to what you posted) from `pipeline.config`

Comment: Would it be possible to know why we need to remove that?